# Conditionally extracting elements from a matrix in Python.

Tags: python, matrix

I am very new to python and I want to extract some elements from a 1911 x 2 matrix such that when elements in column 1 are between two values they will be extracted along with their corresponding element in column 2 to a separate matrix. Unfortunately I cannot just code the matrix indices as the matrix is not always the same.

To give you the context here's the code:

```
 import numpy as np
 import pylab
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 from scipy.optimize import leastsq


data = np.genfromtxt('Ramantest.txt')

x = data[:,] [:,0]
y = data[:,] [:,1]

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

The ouput is this spectrum.
[Spectra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgZc0.png)

I want to extract the elements that correspond to both x and y values on the plot when the x values are between 2600 and 2800.

I thought perhaps using np.hsplit to create a new matrix might be an option, but how can I get the code to identify the elements at which to create the split?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.searchsorted` to get the array indices and use them to slice the original array.

```
range = [800,1000]

idx_low,idx_high = x.searchsorted(data[:,0], range)

data_within_range = data[idx_low:idx_high,:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given any limits `low` and `high`, find the good indices (`low < data[:,0] < high`):

```
np.logical_and(low < data[:,0], data[:,0] < high)
```

Then extract the sub array corresponding to those indices:

```
data[np.logical_and(.low < data[:,0], data[:,0] < high)]
```

This will work even if your `x` data is not sorted.

In your case, it looks like `x` would always be, so you could also find the first indices `i_low` and `i_high` such that `data[0, i_low] > low` and `data[0,i_high] > high` (use `searchsorted` as suggested by Chirstian K.), and then just use a slice: `data[i_low:i_high]`

Comment: Thanks I've tried both methods now, and they not only do they work but I also understand them!  I do have some data I plan to examine where x is not sorted so thank you for providing a complete answer.

Comment: An off-topic comment: have a look at [peak-o-mat](http://lorentz.sf.net) if you are interested in peak fitting of (raman) spectra.